# install jekyll in windows7

Tags: ruby, jekyll

env: windows 7-64bit   DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx    ruby200-64

I already install devkit and ruby. then I  run `gem install jekyll`

looks like something wrong in  ruby.h

it has some errors like follows:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

d:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating stemmer-x64-mingw32.def
compiling porter.c
porter.c: In function 'step1ab':
porter.c:233:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards qualifiers from p  
...
..
compiling porter_wrap.c
In file included from d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:0,from porter_wrap.c:1:
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:125:14: error: size of array 'ruby                                                                                                                      _    check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:0,
             from porter_wrap.c:1:
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_float_value':
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:785:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1214:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1214:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1214:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1215:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1215:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1215:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1515:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
d:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1532:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c: In function 'stem_word':
porter_wrap.c:26:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:26:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:26:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:27:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:27:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:27:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:27:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:27:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:27:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:28:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:28:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:28:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
porter_wrap.c:20:17: warning: unused variable 'i'
make: *** [porter_wrap.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in d:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to d:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
Successfully installed liquid-2.5.1
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

Any assistance would be helpful.thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Ruby is Ruby200-x64, which is 64-bit, so please download the 64-bit DevKit to match your Ruby.

The latest 64-bit DevKit is `DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe`, which can be found [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), while currently yours is 32-bit `DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx`.

Did you notice the difference? Yours is `mingw64-32`, but you need `mingw64-64`.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I encountered here is using Ruby2.00 which seems not an idea version.
The version worked for me is:

1. Ruby 1.9.3-p448
2. DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe

Basically it's just the version issue, other than that , just follow articles you can search around.

Details about where to get these packages:[Issue installing jekyll on windows](http://dannyli.net/notes/fix-problems-of-jekyll-on-windows/)